# WP REST API can't get the products from wp rest api first time connection with node.js

Tags: node.js, wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

not showing any errors. yes this is code I am running with my url and secret keys.Also getting products with these secret keys in postman but not with nodejs.

[Image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxXjo.jpg)

**Code Here**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const cors = require("cors");
const mysql = require("mysql2");


var WooCommerceAPI = require("woocommerce-api");

var WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
  url: "http://mysite.local",
  consumerKey: "my_key",
  consumerSecret: "my_secret",
  wpAPI: true,
  version: "wc/v3"
});

WooCommerce.getAsync("products").then(function(result) {
  return JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body);
});

app.listen("3001", () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3001");
});
```

**Please guide me the or share the updated resources thankyou **

Answer (score 0):

Sorry use these steps then it will work

```
// Install:
// npm install --save @woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api

// Setup:
const WooCommerceRestApi = require("@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api").default;
// import WooCommerceRestApi from "@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api"; // Supports ESM

const WooCommerce = new WooCommerceRestApi({
  url: 'http://example.com', // Your store URL
  consumerKey: 'consumer_key', // Your consumer key
  consumerSecret: 'consumer_secret', // Your consumer secret
  version: 'wc/v3' // WooCommerce WP REST API version
});
```